# What kind of English learner is expected by ELL?

Tags: discussion

When a new member, who is an English learner, joins ELL, what kind of learner that ELL expects to be?

1. A learner who is only a ‘passer-by’? means they join then ask, and leave anytime or leave if they are not satisfied with the service the ELL provides?
2. A learner who can improve their English in a period of time?
3. A learner who stays faithfully in ELL?

Does ELL have the parameter to achieve something in maintaining their learners?

Does ELL expect only more new members with their varied questions?

So, what kind of learner that is expected by ELL actually?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the information in the [help]? There is some information on [why questions are no longer being accepted from an account](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: Also, there is some very good advice for asking in this thread : http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161

Comment: @ColleenV Should I just remove the part about my friend's issue? Because my concern is actually the rest parts. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Please no. You're asking something "directed". When we'd start by saying "ELL is for learners etc.", you're gonna respond with something like "If that's the case, why is . . . ?" No traps please. :) Ask your real question, and I'm more than eager to have a discussion.

Comment: @IͶΔ Oh what trap? is there any trap in learning a language? :( :( :(

Comment: Well then. The answer to your above question is "we're not expecting people to be anything. We, however, expect the content they contribute to be of a minimum quality and that minimum quality is decided by the community as a whole." This is not anything official though. It's just my personal stance.

Comment: Meta is for discussion, so if your friend's issue was troubling to you, I don't see why you wouldn't mention it.

Comment: Your friend's issue is OK to ask about. But as written there is no way to address it, without more detailed information (or a link to a Meta post if it was discussed here) about what happened. As it is, it is more of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to keep in mind is that ELL is a community of all different people and it is open to everyone. Different folks in the community have different ideas about what makes a good question or a good answer, but most of the folks here are constructive when they criticize. [Be Nice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is an important rule of SE sites - if you find a comment or post that isn't nice, flag it for a moderator to look at.

I don't think there is only one type of learner ELL would like. I think that we would like to meet all different sorts of learners, and the standards are more about what types of questions and answers ELL would like. We are trying to build a library that learners of all skill levels can use to find answers to their questions. I think that many of our users never ask a question because they find it has already been answered by searching.

To make ELL a good reference, the questions have to be general enough that they are useful to more than one person. There is a lot of good advice and discussion on this meta site - you may want to sort the questions here by votes and see what topics have been important to the community in the past.

A question about the difference between two words that have similar dictionary definitions, like [Difference between "ignite" and "kindle"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53528/), is something that other learners could benefit from.

A question about a homework question, like [Help understanding a grammar excercise about tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55775/), could be something other learners could benefit from if it has enough explanation. If you check the edit history of that question, it didn't start out as a good question.

A question that asks about one very specific sentence, like https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/81902/, doesn't help anyone but the poster. We're not a free homework or writing service.